# Can I load new content using AJAX, but change the URL in the omnibar?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, html

I don't want to use hashbangs, or shebangs, as they are known. I want to do it the way Facebook does. You click on Profile, the bar remains unchanged and the content is loaded using AJAX. I was wondering if the new HTML5 History API could be used.

EDIT: I think I'm going to go ahead and dive into HTML5's history API. Keeping the question open in case anyone has better suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML 5 history API is the right way to go.

see here: https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2011/02/03/degradable-javascript-applications-using-html5-pushstate/

The pushState and replaceState methods will allow you to change the URL without making an HTTP request. The difference being that pushState pushes a new state on to the history stack, while replaceState replaces the item at the top of the stack.

Comment: That's what I'd thought. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at [jquery-pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that.  You can just prevent the default action from occuring.  For instance, with jQuery we have;

```
function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // this is different from event.stopPropogation()
  // do some stuff
}
```

this will prevent the link's default action (following the url) from occurring.

P.S. I've always heard shebang refers specifically to this: `#!`, and not just `#`, but I could be misinformed...

Comment: Yes, shebang (aka hashbang) is `#!`. The `#` as used in URLs is just a hash.

Comment: I know that I can prevent default action. But clicking on a link with its default action prevented won't change the URL. I want people to be able to share the link of the page, in its current state, with the AJAX content loaded. For example, I'm on foo.com. I click on home, load content using AJAX, but the URL hasn't changed because I prevented it from changing. I want people to see foo.com/home or something like that in the URL bar even though I haven't actually changed the URL.

Comment: in that case, pushState is the correct way to go -- I think I misunderstood your question